# Video mousehover que haga play solo el video.webm

Tags: javascript, html

primero felicitar el nuevo año a todos los participantes de este gran foro.
Ahora si, mi problema es que tengo una etiqueta video con dos source, uno es .mp4 y otro es .webm, al hacer hover en el se reproduce el webm, que es el de 30s y de hecho es lo que quiero. Aparentemente todo funciona, pero no del todo, os dejo el cdigo.

etiqueta video:

```
<div class="video">

   <video class="thevideo" loop>
      <source src="<?php echo $previews['volles-video']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="<?php echo $previews['kurzes-video']; ?>" type="video/webm"> 
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

</div>
```

y aqui el codigo javascript:

```
var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
   $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
   $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
```

Y el navegador me da el siguiente error:

main.js?ver=1:14 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

y me dice que el fallo esta aqui

$('video', this).get(0).play();

Pero yo no lo encuentro, el codigo es muy basico ya que estoy aun aprendiendo javascript, como hace un par de meses atras...Si alguien me puede ayudar, lo agradeceria, un saludo

Comment: Hola @Dario B. feliz año a ti tambien!! no queda claro lo que quieres hacer.La idea es que si pasas el ratón por encima se reproduzca el primer link o que quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: A ver, el priemr source es el video completo, y el segundo es un webm de unos pocos segundos, es basicamente el efecto de youtube, peeeeero, ya encontre el fallo, lo pongo aqui debajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al final lo he solucionado recordando un tema que **pasa solo con chrome**.
En las etiquetas  se debe siempre colocar el muted con el autoplay, ya que chrome no acepta el autoplay y escupe el fallo que me dio.
Por lo tanto la solucion pasa a quedar asi:

```
 <video class="thevideo" loop autoplay muted>
    <source src="<?php echo $previews['volles-video']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="<?php echo $previews['kurzes-video']; ?>" type="video/webm"> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```